# How to insert a primary/foreign key row in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, insert, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm populating a database in PostgreSQL for a Newspaper Online. Now my doubt lies on how to insert a value into a table which only attribute is both a primary and a foreign key.

In this context, the admin is the first person to ever register an account. So idAdmin = idA = 1:

```
CREATE TABLE AUTENTICADO (
    idA serial NOT NULL ,
    login VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idA) );

CREATE TABLE ADMIN (
    idAdmin INT  NOT NULL REFERENCES AUTENTICADO (idA),
    PRIMARY KEY (idAdmin) );
```

It would be logical to insert values into 'ADMIN' as I tried below, although it is obviously not possible considering 'idAdmin' is a primary key (and a foreign key).

```
INSERT INTO AUTENTICADO VALUES ('john','adadfsfsdfs', 'john@random.com')
INSERT INTO ADMIN VALUES (1)
```

Is there a way to register that the first user to create an account (idA = 1) is the admin (idAdmin = idA = 1) ?

Comment: What if you create AUTENTICADO record first (idA=1), and then insert the admin which refere to the inserted AUTENTICADO ? I certainly did not understand the problem!

Comment: @Houari I've already created several registers for AUTENTICADO (added to the code above), but I cannot insert it into ADMIN because it is a primary key. Gives me an error.

Comment: @Khabz Can you indicate the **exact** error that you are receiving when trying to insert in the ADMIN table?

Answer (score 1):

> although it is obviously not possible considering 'idAdmin' is a
>   primary key (and a foreign key).

So what?

If you fix the first query to list the columns and use a `returning` clause to get the auto-generated value for the `SERIAL` ID, it just works:

```
INSERT INTO AUTENTICADO(login,password,email)
  VALUES ('john','adadfsfsdfs', 'john@random.com')
  returning idA;
```

Result:

```
 ida 
-----
   1
(1 row)
```

Second query:

```
insert into admin values(1);
select * from admin;
```

Result:

```
 idadmin 
---------
       1
```